# Nodejs Express Receive Data From ZKTeco Device

Tags: node.js

I have a zkteco WL30 device which can push attendance to a provided IP address. I have created a new nodejs-express project and added a POST endpoint to it to receive the data. I can successfully receive the request but not the data. Attendance data is completely missing from request object - neither in the body nor in data.

I have also tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/zklib but it doesn't connect to the device. The included device software however successfully receive all data successfully.

Here is the node-express code I'm using -

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

app.post('/iclock/cdata.aspx', function(request, response) {
    response.send("OK\n");
});

app.get('/iclock/cdata.aspx', function(request, response) {
    response.headers["content-type"] = "text/plain";
    response.send("OK\n");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')});
```

Can anyone suggest a way of receiving attendance in nodejs application?

Comment: post the code that creates your server

Comment: @GiannisMp done.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this, actually https://www.npmjs.com/package/zklib is connecting to device successfully, just tried.

Comment: Greetings ! What should be filled in the ip address in zklib ! how can i get the device IP ? help me @AdizbekErgashev

Comment: Hello @EfrainSanjayAdhikary. First you should set ip to device(in settings of device), in my case it's 192.168.1.201, and port is as default 4370.